# Directory Listing issue with Apache/Flask

Tags: python, apache, flask

Directory listing under apache/flask.
I have a flask running under apache web server, and this is the conf file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/Documents/wsgi/scripts/wiki
ServerName name

WSGIScriptAlias / /Library/WebServer/Documents/wsgi/scripts/wiki.wsgi

<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents/wsgi/scripts/wiki">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride AuthConfig All 
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/wiki_error_log"

</VirtualHost>
```

The issue is that even with the `Options Indexes`, I cannot access the contents in the wiki directory. For example trying to access static directory (.../wiki/static/) gives me this "Not Found" error.

What might be wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/static/` is being routed through Flask. If you put a file in that directory and request it: `/wiki/static/file.jpg` it should work. Flask does not supply an index for the root of the static folder like Apache does.

That said, it's best to route your static files directly through your webserver (Apache) and not through Flask.