# Deploy Flask in Apache, and still enable Apache Directory Listing

Tags: python, flask, apache2, wsgi, directory-listing

I have written a Flask app, which is running through Apache on a Docker-Container.

The flask app is vulnerable on purpose!

It is designed to teach students about Secure Coding.

To make the website even "weaker" I want Directory Listing be enabled, so it is possible to just browse through the servers files.

I have tried the following as config file for apache:

```
`<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 127.0.0.1
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /app

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /app>
        Options Indexes followSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess app python-path=/app:/app/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup app
    WSGIScriptAlias / /app/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>`
```

But all i get is a "Not Found" reply, from the server when I try to e.g visit: http://localhost:8080/app

The flask app itself still works as intended.

I have also tried to run everything as a Proxy, but it seems that Flask has its own problems running with such a configuration, which I have also tried to fix but they did not seem to work yet.

I have also found this ARticle: [Directory Listing issue with Apache/Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27284196/directory-listing-issue-with-apache-flask)

But i dont understand how to route specific files through apache instead of flask.